# Spacing between two buttons in RelativeLayout in Android xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout that has two buttons. I'm trying to set the relative positions of these two dynamically so that on different screen sizes, it looks same. The position of the layout is getting set correctly basing on screen size but the spacing between the buttons is not getting.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonLine"
        android:layout_above="@+id/separator">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="@drawable/skip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"/>



    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonClr"
        android:background="@drawable/clear"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

In my java class I have a method for the dynamic part. I'm using this piece of code there for this button-relative-layout.

```
button_line.getLayoutParams().height = getHorizontalRatio(40); //button_line is RelativeLayout
 skip.setPadding(getHorizontalRatio(40), 0, 0, 0); //skip and clear are the buttons
 clear.setPadding(getHorizontalRatio(400), 0, 0, 0);
skip.getLayoutParams().width = getHorizontalRatio(75);
            skip.getLayoutParams().height = getHorizontalRatio(25);
            clear.getLayoutParams().width = getHorizontalRatio(75);
            clear.getLayoutParams().height = getHorizontalRatio(25);
```

PS: I have tried changing the ratios and changing the layout to LinearLayout(which I didn't understand completely). Please suggest something.

Comment: try using LinearLayout with layout_weight

Comment: @wisemann tried that but the code I wrote, didn't work. Any example code or links?

Comment: I added answer, check pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:padding="20dp"
              android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: this is what I did first but the result is not consistent. on different devices the left and right margins are getting out of proportions.

Comment: Left and right margin must be same on every device. I can not understand your situation. Can you explain more?

Comment: The 10dp value that you're setting as margin, I did same like that. But on trying the app on samsung tab, samsung galaxy S and Moto G, i found that the proportions of the margins are not same.

Comment: If you use 'dp' margin appears same by physically. If you want to scale by width of device, use 'px'.

Comment: how do I add two more rows like this ? In other words, I need to have 6 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Android auto take care for the positioning of elements with respect to screen size.
We use dp (density pixels) as a unit to give margins or padding, which in return will place the elements with respect to the screen size of the device.

Check out this link for further details:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

So, as a conclusion, you don't have to set the padding during runtime, you can make the changes in your layout xml.

Edit try using this, snippet from one of my working project!!..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
 <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
     android:text="CLEAR"
     android:id="@+id/clearBtn"/>
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="SEARCH"
        android:id="@+id/searchBtn"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this works..

Comment: I've tried using a dp value as margins but that didn't work out with multiple screens of varying sizes. Anymore suggestions?  :-(

Answer (score 0):

not very good at performance but works fine :)

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/buttonLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/separator"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/skip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonClr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/clear" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

For more details: [Layout Weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear_btn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_clear"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/skip_btn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_skip"
        android:padding="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
android:layout_marginRight="60dp">

   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:background="@drawable/skip" />

   <View
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"/>

   <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/buttonClr"
       android:background="@drawable/clear />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TableLayout`and play with the weight property to adjust the spacing you need. The `TextView` between your buttons will be used as spacer.

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
              android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:weightSum = 11>

              <Button
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/button"
                  android:layout_weight="5"
                  android:background="@drawable/skip"/>

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/TextView04" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"/>

              <Button
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/buttonClr"
                  android:layout_weight="5"
                  android:background="@drawable/clear"/>

        </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Add this table layout inside your `RelativeLayout`.

Hope it helps.